# Keycloak - Add roles to the user profile

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak on one of my projects. On the backend I am using sringboot and calling Keycloak REST API.

I would love to have info about roles (better would be client's roles, but realm roles will be sufficient) of each users, when fetching it's profile.

URL where I am trying to fetch user: `<host>/admin/realms/<realm>/users/<id>`

At this moment, I have to programmatically loop over each user and fetch his roles. Which means many and many additional requests. Imagine having 500 users... And yes, I know I could paginate them etc.

I have been trying to find something on the internet for sooo long time, but nothing works. I am able to add them to the access token, but I can't add them to the user info.

If there is anyone who knows how to enrich user info, just point me the right directions. I have been messing with client scopes for so long and I still don't understand them at all. I could not even find a good tutorial on this topic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should develop your own KeyCloak extension:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions_rest

You need java and nhibernate skills.

Comment: okay, this is a little bit too much for adding just 1 parameter to the object... But Definitely a way how to achieve it.

Comment: It is too much if you don't have performance problems with your current implementation.

Comment: I guess I have to accept this answer, because there is propably no other way. Anyway, I hope this answer will help others when searching for a same question.